# "Мы () да!" — нужны ли знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая (или еще какой-то разделительный знак: тире, двоеточие)?

***А вы знаете секрет общения с ребенком? Мы ( ) да!***

В предложении — "Мы () да!" — **как правильно?**
*"Мы — да!*", или *"Мы, да!"*, или *"Мы: да!"*, или вообще без знаков? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

**А вы знаете секрет общения с ребенком? Мы — да!**

Тире ставится в **неполном** предложении: Мы  — да (знаем)!

Возможен такой ответ: Да, мы знаем. Но при инверсии и неполном  ответе тире является единственно возможным знаком. Тире обозначает разделительную паузу, интонация восходяще-нисходящая, при этом предложение делится на две части.

**Двоеточие** имеет пояснительный характер, поэтому в этом случае не подходит. **Запятая** также не соответствует данной конструкции.

Comment: А по-моему, тире нужно было бы поставить даже в полном предложении. "Мы - знаем!". То есть неполнота предложения - сомнительный аргумент.